# how do the main entities in flask interplay

Tags: python, flask, localhost

- I am (rather) new to flask
- I understand the following entities exist

  - `wsgi.py`
  - `endpoints.py`
- How should the decorators in `endpoints.py` know about `app`?

  - `endpoints` importing `wsgi` "feels" wrong (or doesn't it ?!)
- Here is my solution without *decorators at all*:

```
$ tree -P "*.py"
.
├── api
│   ├── endpoints.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── wsgi.py
└── tests
    └── send_post_request_to_localhost.py
```

I put "everything" inside the `wsgi.py` as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from api.endpoints import analyze

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.add_url_rule( # <----- this way app is "encapsulated" in wsgi
        "/api/v1/system/analyze",
        view_func=analyze,
        methods=["POST"]
    )
    app.run()
```

and so my endpoints are *pure* and *flask-less*:

```
from typing import List, Dict, Union
from flask import request, jsonify

def analyze() -> List[Dict[str, Union[int, str]]]:

    return jsonify([
        {
            "name": "dear " + entry["name"],
            "salary": entry["salary"] + 37
        }
        for entry in request.get_json()
        if request.is_json
    ])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask application itself is WSGI application where WSGI server is provided by other component (mod_wsgi, gunicorn). The typical setup follows documented patterns which provides convenient separation of app into appropriate python modules solving both circular imports issues as well as scaling codebase.

- factory pattern -- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/appfactories/
- blueprints -- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/blueprints/

That allows to make binding the app to WSGI server versatile (either via `wsgi.py` or other means). The actual code in `wsgi.py` then contains only the "binding" but not the app impl itself.

- `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from endpoints import bp

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/')
    return app
```

- `endpoints.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

bp = Blueprint('endpoints', __name__)

@bp.route('/api/v1/system/analyze', methods=['POST'])
## not sure about types here, the flask view function must return flask.Response
def analyze():  
    return jsonify([
        {
            "name": "dear " + entry["name"],
            "salary": entry["salary"] + 37
        }
        for entry in request.get_json()
        if request.is_json
    ])
```

- `wsgi.py`

```
applicaton = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Great source for inspiration might be tutorial app https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/examples/tutorial/flaskr/ or other community examples https://github.com/carc1n0gen/flask-examples/tree/master/flask-starter.